# Couchbase Document Expiry isn't working with spring-data-couchbase:.4.0.3.RELEASE

Tags: spring, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

Tried setting expiry to 60 seconds on a document as mentioned in below reference document with spring-data-couchbase-4.0.3.RELEASE lib. However, the expiry doesn't work as resets the value to 0.

[spring-data-couchbase reference document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#reference)

I have found that the value is being reset to 0 in ReactiveUpsertByIdOperationSupport class file in below method.

```
private UpsertOptions buildUpsertOptions() {
    final UpsertOptions options = UpsertOptions.upsertOptions();
    if (persistTo != PersistTo.NONE || replicateTo != ReplicateTo.NONE) {
        options.durability(persistTo, replicateTo);
    } else if (durabilityLevel != DurabilityLevel.NONE) {
        options.durability(durabilityLevel);
    }
    return options;
}
```

Not sure how I can fix this issue. Any help is appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: Here's the issue tracker if you want to report a bug: https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATACOUCH/

Comment: Thanks @dnault. Looks like Michael Reiche below created an issue.